# DOCX viewer in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is DOCX viewer in flutter possible.

I have tried PDFTron, it has the following drawbacks:

1. Not a widget
2. Paid version

If DOCX viewer is not available, then is DOCX to PDF converter available?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-pdf), but if you want and offline solution i do not believe i came across one or you can use[FFI](https://pub.dev/packages/ffi) if you found a native code for conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [flutter_filereader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) package. It has a lot of file types. I suggest to you.

Comment: flutter_filereader is in Chinese and it always gives out "Engine load failed, please quit and try again"

Comment: did you find solution because im also working but unable to customize all chinese and facing same problem Engine load fail